# Extra point with Symbols for footnotes in babel

Tags: footnotes, babel

I need to use French typography, thus babel with the French option. The number of a footnote is correctly on the line, followed by a point. But I also need to have one footnote with a symbol instead of a number. I know how to do this (thanks to previous posts!), except that the point still appears after the symbol, which it should not. How to get rid of the point in this case, and only in this case ?

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,twoside,openright]{book}

\usepackage[body={110mm, 185mm}, headheight=20pt]{geometry} 
\usepackage[french]{babel}   
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}      

\makeatletter
\def\@xfootnote[#1]{
 \protected@xdef\@thefnmark{#1}%
 \@footnotemark\@footnotetext}
 \makeatother


 \begin{document}

 Une note normale\footnote{Note en francais.}.
 Une note bizarre\footnote[*]{GLURPS.}.
 Une autre note normale\footnote{Note en francais.}.
 \end{document}
```

[image: Footnotes in French with symbols]

Answer (score 4):

The following example patches the case of `\footnote`, when the optional argument is given and `\@xfootnote` is called. Then `\insertfootnoteFB@dotless` is called instead of `\insertfootnoteFB` to remove the dot.

It remains unclear, where the space of the dot goes:

- The footnote symbol uses the space:

  ```
  \kern1\wd\@tempboxa
  \llap{\@thefnmark}%
  \kern0\wd\@tempboxa
  ```
- The footnote symbol does *not* use the space:

  ```
  \kern0\wd\@tempboxa
  \llap{\@thefnmark}%
  \kern1\wd\@tempboxa
  ```
- Or something inbetween: The factors for the width of `\@tempboxa` which contains the dot must sum up to 1.

Full example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,twoside,openright]{book}

\usepackage[
  % body={110mm, 185mm},
  body={120mm, 30mm}, % smaller image for TeX.SX
  headheight=20pt,
]{geometry}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{letltxmacro}

\makeatletter
\def\@xfootnote[#1]#2{
  \protected@xdef\@thefnmark{#1}%
  \@footnotemark
  \begingroup
    \let\insertfootnotemarkFB\insertfootnotemarkFB@dotless
    \@footnotetext{#2}%
  \endgroup
}
\newcommand*{\insertfootnotemarkFB@dotless}{%
  \parindent=\parindentFFN
  \rule\z@\footnotesep
  \setbox\@tempboxa\hbox{\@thefnmark}%
  \ifdim\wd\@tempboxa>\z@
    \setbox\@tempboxa\hbox{\dotFFN}%
    \kern1\wd\@tempboxa
    \llap{\@thefnmark}%
    \kern0\wd\@tempboxa
    \kernFFN
  \fi
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
  Une note normale\footnote{Note en francais.}.
  Une note bizarre\footnote[*]{GLURPS.}.
  Une autre note normale\footnote{Note en francais.}.
\end{document}
```

With the footnote symbol right aligned to the complete footnote markers with dots:

> [image: Result]

Or with the footnote symbol right aligned with the numbers without dots:

> [image: Result]

Comment: Thanks a lot. But when I copy the code above and "LaTeX" it, it does not work, I have still the dot! Do I need anything special ?

Comment: @Catherine Does the unmodified example of the answer work? What does "does not work" mean? MWE?

Comment: I copy the "full example" above (with the \newcommand*{\insertfootnotemarkFB@dotless etc). It produces all the footnotes with a dot after the notemark, including the one with the star. That is, it does exactly the same as in my example. I cannot reproduce any of your two versions (I am interested in the one  with the symbol aligned with the numbers).

Comment: @Catherine What happens, if you run the example of the answer (errors, warnings, output, version)?

Comment: Nothing happens! It seems perfect, everything runs smoothly and the result is the same as before (with a dot). Reading your example, I convinced myself that I need to understand more how the footnote was shaped in babel-french and I just wrote to Daniel Flipo (who did it). He answered with a solution to my problem. I enter it. Thanks a lot for your answer, it  helped me to clarify the issue very much

Answer (score 1):

This answer comes from Daniel Flipo (babel-french). It explains how to shape a footnote with a dot locally (combined with the definition of  \footnote[mark]{text} given in my question.

```
% English presentation (locally)
{\makeatletter\renewcommand\thefootnote{\@fnsymbol\c@footnote}\makeatother
\FBFrenchFootnotesfalse
Note\footnote[*]{une astérisque.}
étoilée
}

% French presentation, locally, without a dot
{\makeatletter\renewcommand\thefootnote{\@fnsymbol\c@footnote}\makeatother
\renewcommand{\dotFFN}{}\renewcommand{\kernFFN}{\hphantom{.}\kern .5em}
Note\footnote[*]{Une astérisque sur la ligne de base.}
étoilée
}
```